# Refactor cypher query for batchquery using apoc

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am in the process of refactoring this cypher query

```
    MERGE(n:Entity:{type_} {{ent_id: "ABC123"}})
    ON CREATE SET n.literal_forms = ["new label"]
    ON MATCH SET n.literal_forms = apoc.coll.toSet(n.literal_forms + "new label")
```

to take a list of MAP structures (to be used with UNWIND) to be more performant for batch querying.

My idea to address first struggle was to call `apoc.coll.toSet` (since I need to reference the matched node, if any) within my query and for this I am trying to use `apoc.do.case` to handle the logic implemented in `ON MATCH` above.

So far I have something like

```
    UNWIND $attribs as row
    CALL apoc.merge.node.eager(["Entity", row.type_], {ent_id: row.ent_match_crit}, {literal_forms: [row.literal_form]}, {}) yield node as n1
    with n1, row
    CALL apoc.do.case([
        size(n1.literal_forms) >= 1,
        "MATCH (n1) SET n1.literal_forms = apoc.coll.toSet(n1.literal_forms + row.literal_form)"
    ]) yield value
    RETURN value.node as node
```

where `$attribs` would be something like:

```
[{"type_": "Gene", "ent_match_crit": "CHEMBL2108755", "literal_form": "penicillinase"}, {"type_": "Gene", "ent_match_crit": "GO0008800", "literal_form": "beta-lactamase"}]
```

but this query does not write to my database (on `merge.node` nor within the `case.do`. When I plug in sample values this query appears to work in neo4j browser but not when I execute within my code using a list of map structures. Can someone please help me?

Also, does anyone see a better way to do what it is that I am trying to do?

BTW the reason I need to use `apoc.merge.node` is because I need to dynamically create/match nodes label types.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: when I comment out the `case.do` clause, the `merge.node` does write to the db which leads me to think something is wrong within my `apoc.do.case` segment.

Comment: Another update: plugging in a param in neo4j browser I get this as an error: 
```
Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.case`: Caused by: org.neo4j.exceptions.SyntaxException: Variable `row` not defined (line 1, column 70 (offset: 69))
"MATCH (n1) SET n1.literal_forms = apoc.coll.toSet(n1.literal_forms + row.literal_form)"
``` So the question now is, can I smuggle row into this query?

Answer (score 0):

After a good nights sleep I realized I had overcomplicated things a bit and have come up with this solution:

```
    UNWIND $attribs as row
    CALL apoc.merge.node.eager(["Entity", row.type_], {ent_id: row.ent_match_crit}, {literal_forms: []}, {}) yield node as n1
    with n1, row.literal_form as lf, n1.literal_forms as node_literals
    SET n1.literal_forms = apoc.coll.toSet(node_literals + lf)
    RETURN n1
```

This query works as expected.

Let me know if anyone sees a better way to do this :)